# Visual Studio Build Events for Javascript projects

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, winjs

I'd like to run a script (pre-build or post-build) when I build my jsproj from Visual Studio 2012. I've tried right-clicking the jsproj and the Solution, and going to properties but I can't find the "compile" tab or any "build events" button. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by modifying the .jsproj file by hand, see related question [How do I create a pre-build step for a javascript metro app in VS11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584823/how-do-i-create-a-pre-build-step-for-a-javascript-metro-app-in-vs11)

Comment: Correct--the VS UI doesn't provide for custom jsproj steps, but you can do it via hand editing. It's helpful in that case to know about the Task Reference (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx) that describes what you can put inside the Target element.